# Socket.io - How secure is their session management?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I am currently developing a web application and would like to introduce some basic security measures into it. In context of that, I am investigating whether the vanilla approach socket.io uses to handle sessions with users is safe. From [this article](https://aslamanver.medium.com/socket-io-session-handler-for-node-js-90c15519fa02) I found out that for each connection socket.io receives it generates an ID (even if it's just a new browser tab). I guess this could be seen as a very basic session ID. Now my question is, how is this ID generated and is it random enough to ensure no one could hijack the session by guessing (whether it is by brute-force or some statistiscs) such ID of an active user?

As some people asked for clarification: I am trying to avoid session hijacking by an attacker. Whether this by because an attacker can easily brute force session ID's, guess it using some statistiscs due to it not being random enough or being able to steal it using network sniffing/XSS to steal the cookie its stored in.

Comment: ***"some basic security measures"*** is very generic.  What exactly are you trying to do and what exactly do you want to protect from?

Comment: Added clarification.

Comment: To protect again networking sniffing, you HAVE to use HTTPS.  That is generic for the whole transport, not just for socket.io.

Comment: Yup, I make sure of HTTPS. In regards to XSS I also verified the cookie uses the HttpOnly flag.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what "security" you are trying to implement or what you are trying to protect from.  As for the sessionid, here's how that is generated and then you can decide if this meets your needs or not.

First off, socket.io uses a method called `.generateId()` to create the new ID.  It has a default implementation (which we will get to in a second), but you can also replace it with your mechanism if you want per the [doc here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#server-engine-generateId).

Then, here's the [default implementation](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/c099338e04bb5a93b8997c871c27d238455d2deb/lib/server.js#L219):

```
    generateId(req) {
      return base64id.generateId();
    }
```

which obviously just calls the [base64id module](https://github.com/faeldt/base64id/blob/master/lib/base64id.js#L80) which uses this code:

```
Base64Id.prototype.generateId = function () {
  var rand = Buffer.alloc(15); // multiple of 3 for base64
  if (!rand.writeInt32BE) {
    return Math.abs(Math.random() * Math.random() * Date.now() | 0).toString()
      + Math.abs(Math.random() * Math.random() * Date.now() | 0).toString();
  }
  this.sequenceNumber = (this.sequenceNumber + 1) | 0;
  rand.writeInt32BE(this.sequenceNumber, 11);
  if (crypto.randomBytes) {
    this.getRandomBytes(12).copy(rand);
  } else {
    // not secure for node 0.4
    [0, 4, 8].forEach(function(i) {
      rand.writeInt32BE(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 32) | 0, i);
    });
  }
  return rand.toString('base64').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');
};
```

If running the server on nodejs where the `crypto` module exists, this will call `this.getRandomBytes()` and that code is included in that same module which you can look at.  It uses `crypto.randomBytes(12)`.

You can then decide for yourself if that meets your security needs.  Or you could replace it with a different id generator that did meet your needs.  FYI, a 12 byte random number is pretty hard to guess.  That's 256 raised to the 12th power sized id space.  256^12 is 7.9228163e+28.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I added clarification on what I exactly want to secure against. I read [this article](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Insufficient_Session-ID_Length#:~:text=Session%20identifiers%20should%20be%20at,brute%2Dforce%20session%20guessing%20attacks.) in regards to how long a session ID should minimally be to be considered 'secure'. This suggests 128 bits of length, while socket.io seems to generate ids of length 96 bits long. You rekkon they exaggerate it a bit and 96 should be enough to not warrant to completely change this code?

Comment: @Astarno - It really depends upon what's at stake and for how long you are going to have a persistent session.  For the passwords to my financial accounts, I'd hold a little bit different standard than my gaming session. 96 bits is pretty good.  128 bits is better, but how much better may be irrelevant and thus the extra work might be a waste of effort that could be better spent on other things depending upon what you're actually trying to protect and for how long.